# LazyColumnFor is not smooth scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

So, I have implemented a lazycolumnfor to work with a list of recipe elements, the thing is that it does not smooth scroll, if I just scroll fast it stutters till the last element appears and not smooth scroll.

Is this an error from my side or do I need to add something else?

```
    data class Recipe(
            @DrawableRes val imageResource: Int,
            val title: String,
            val ingredients: List<String>
    )
    
    val recipeList = listOf(
            Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Cake1", listOf("Cheese","Sugar","water")),
            Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Cake2", listOf("Cheese1","Sugar1","Vanilla")),
            Recipe(R.drawable.header,"Cake3", listOf("Bread","Sugar2","Apple")))
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                RecipeList(recipeList = recipeList)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun RecipeCard(recipe:Recipe){
        val image = imageResource(R.drawable.header)
        Surface(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),elevation = 8.dp,modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                val imageModifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(150.dp).fillMaxWidth().clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                Image(asset = image,modifier = imageModifier,contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))
                Text(text = recipe.title,style = typography.h6)
                for(ingredient in recipe.ingredients){
                    Text(text = ingredient,style = typography.body2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun RecipeList(recipeList:List<Recipe>){
        LazyColumnFor(items = recipeList) { item ->
            RecipeCard(recipe = item)
        }
    }

@Preview
@Composable
fun RecipePreview(){
    RecipeCard(recipeList[0])
}
```

Comment: try removing `Image` from your `ReceipeCard`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (version `1.0.0-alpha02`) Jetpack Compose has 2 Composable functions for loading image resources:

1. `imageResource()`: this Composable function, load an image resource **synchronously**.
2. `loadImageResource()`: this function loads the image in a **background thread**, and once the loading finishes, recompose is scheduled and this function will return deferred image resource with `LoadedResource` or `FailedResource`

So your `lazyColumn` is not scrolling smoothly since you are loading images synchronously.

So you should either use `loadImageResource()` or a library named `Accompanist` by Chris Banes,  which can fetch and display images from external sources, such as network, using the Coil image loading library.

**UPDATE:**

**Using `CoilImage` :**

First, add [Accompanist](https://github.com/chrisbanes/accompanist) Gradle dependency, then simply use `CoilImage` composable function:

```
    CoilImage(data = R.drawable.header)
```

**Using `loadImageResource()` :**

```
    val deferredImage = loadImageResource(
        id = R.drawable.header,
    )

    val imageModifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(150.dp).fillMaxWidth()
        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    deferredImage.resource.resource?.let {
        Image(
            asset = it,
            modifier = imageModifier
        )
    }
```

Note: I tried both ways in a `LazyColumnFor`, and although `loadImageResource()` performed better than `imageResource()` but still it didn't scroll smoothly.

**So I highly recommend using `CoilImage`**

Note 2: To use Glide or Picasso, check [this repository](https://github.com/vinaygaba/Learn-Jetpack-Compose-By-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetpackcompose/image/ImageActivity.kt#L223) by Vinay Gaba

Comment: Could you please add how to integrate it with my current code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the other note, LazyColumn haven't been optimised for scrolling performance yet, but I've just tested on `1.0.0-beta07` release and can confirm it's way smoother than `1.0.0-beta06`

Compose.UI `1.0.0-beta07` relevant change log:

> LazyColumn/Row will now keep up to 2 previously visible items active (not disposed) even when they are scrolled out already. This allows the component to reuse the active subcompositions when we will need to compose a new item which improves the scrolling performance. (Ie5555)